# Create "check all" / "select all" checkbox with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have few checkboxes , out of which one is "Select All" and the others are some standalone's.

The requirement is that

1. Ifthe user click on "Select All" checkbox, then all other checkboxes will be checked.
2. If he unchecks the "Select All" checkbox , then everything will be unchecked.
3. And if any one of the individual checkbox is unchecked, then the "Select all" will be unchecked.
4. If all the four check boxes are checked, then the "Select All" will be checked.

I am using JQuery. I am able to achieve the first two but not the last two. My code is as under

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> Check / UnCheck All Checkbox </TITLE> 

  <script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function SelectDeselect()
  {
        if(document.getElementById('chkSelectDeselectAll').checked)  $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked',true); 

        else  $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked',false); 
  }

  </script>

 </HEAD>

 <BODY>


    <input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectDeselectAll" onClick="SelectDeselect()">Select All
    <br><br>

    Select your hobbies:
    <br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkTV">Watching T.V.<br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkGardening">Gardening<br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkSwimming">Swimming<br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkChess">Playing Chess<br><br>

 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Need help to implement the rest.

Thanks

Comment: what version are you using of jQuery? and bind javascript click with jQuery rather then add it in the HTML markup

Comment: a bit older(1.2.6).Sir I am not very proficient in JQuery.Just started learning because we r implementing in the current project

Comment: 1.2.6 is not "old" ... it's **ancient** :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function checkOne(){
    if(    document.getElementById('chkTV').checked &&
          document.getElementById('chkGardening').checked &&
    document.getElementById('chkSwimming').checked &&
    document.getElementById('chkChess').checked ){
         document.getElementById('chkSelectDeselectAll').checked = true;
    }
    else{
         document.getElementById('chkSelectDeselectAll').checked = false;
    }

  }



    <input type="checkbox" id="chkTV" onclick="checkOne">Watching T.V.<br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkGardening" onclick="checkOne">Gardening<br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkSwimming" onclick="checkOne">Swimming<br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkChess" onclick="checkOne">Playing Chess<br><br>
```

Comment: The answer should have been more GENERIC. It won't be handy if there are 'n' numbers of checkboxes. You just cannot put all checkboxes in IF statement like that!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#main').change(function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input[name="hi[]"]:checkbox').attr('checked', true);        

        } else {

            $('input[name="hi[]"]:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });


$('input[name="hi[]"]:checkbox').change(function() {
        var chkLength = $('input[name="hi[]"]:checkbox').length;
        var checkedLen = $('input[name="hi[]"]:checkbox:checked').length;    
        if (chkLength == checkedLen) {
            $('#main').attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('#main').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
​
```

CHeck Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4vKwm/10/

Answer (score 2):

maybe it gives some explanations

Ifthe user click on "Select All" checkbox, then all other checkboxes will be checked.

```
    $("#chkSelectDeselectAll").click(function(){  
     if($("#chkSelectDeselectAll").is(':checked'))
{
        ("checkbox").each(function(){
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
          });
}
    });
```

If he unchecks the "Select All" checkbox , then everything will be unchecked.

```
$("#chkSelectDeselectAll").click(function(){  
     if(!$("#chkSelectDeselectAll").is(':checked'))
{
    ("checkbox").each(function(){
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
          });
    }
});
```

And if any one of the individual checkbox is unchecked, then the "Select all" will be unchecked.

```
$("checkbox").click(function(){
    ("checkbox").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
            $("#chkSelectDeselectAll").removeAttr('checked');
    }
          });
     });
```

If all the four check boxes are checked, then the "Select All" will be checked.

```
$("checkbox").click(function(){
    ("checkbox").each(function(){
    var yesno=true;
    if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
    {
            yesno=false;
    }
          });
    if( yesno)
    {
     $("#chkSelectDeselectAll").attr('checked', 'checked')
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the state of all checkboxes.

<strike>Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XSdjQ/1/</strike>

<strike>Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XSdjQ/2/</strike>

Yet another Demo that works nicely with your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/XSdjQ/3/

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend you to update your jQuery library and try to add a class to all the checkboxes you want to listen to, but:

```
var collection = $("input:checkbox:not(#chkSelectDeselectAll)").change(function() {
    selectAll[0].checked = collection.filter(":not(:checked)").length === 0;
});
var selectAll = $("#chkSelectDeselectAll").change(function(){
    collection.attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

will work, I added the feature if you manually check all (or deselect one when you pushed select all) then it will toggle off the `#chkSelectDeselectAll`. A demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/yTWKY/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chkSelectDeselectAll').toggle(function(){
                $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('checked',true);
                });

    },function(){
                $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
                    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                });
    })
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id*=chkAll]").bind("click", function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("[id*=chkvalue] input").attr("checked", "checked");
                } else {
                    $("[id*=chkvalue] input").removeAttr("checked");
                }
            });
            $("[id*=chkvalue] input").bind("click", function () {
                if ($("[id*=chkvalue] input:checked").length == $("[id*=chkvalue] input").length) {
                    $("[id*=chkAll]").attr("checked", "checked");
                } else {
                    $("[id*=chkAll]").removeAttr("checked");
                }
            });
        });
</script>



<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" Text="Select All Test Patterns" runat="server" />

 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkvalue" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="On/Off" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Alternate Rows" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Alternate Columns" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Alternate Diagonals" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Running Row" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Running Columns" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```